# mediafilesegmenter with encryption

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing

I'm trying to use encryption with the mediafilesegmenter and although I think I've got everything set up correctly, the videos are refusing to play.

I'm segmenting the files with the following command:

```
mediafilesegmenter -O -K http://www.mydomain.com/ipad/crypt.key -f /Users/pls/Sites/videos/212/h /Users/pls/Sites/processing/212-h.m4v
```

The file at http://www.mydomain.com/ipad/crypt.key is a 16-byte key file created by mediafilesegmenter using the command:

```
mediafilesegmenter -O -K http://www.mydomain.com/ipad/crypt.key -k crypt.key -g -f /Users/pls/Sites/videos/212/h /Users/pls/Sites/processing/212-h.m4v
```

Once segmented I'm uploading to the webserver and trying to play the streams by pointing to the main .m3u8 file but I'm not getting anything - it's finding the file but then not playing.  If anyone has any thoughts or better yet a working example of segmenting a file with encryption with the commands used that would be great.

Comment: An update to this:  It turns out if I generate the encryption key when I segment the files then everything works great, BUT I need to know how to then use that same encryption key when segmenting subsequent files.  In other words the second command listed above (with the -g option) results in files that  play back ok, but then trying to use the same command minus the -g option (to prevent encryption key generation) doesn't work - it just returns to the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - I needed to update mediafilesegmenter to the latest version.  After doing so, the command

```
mediafilesegmenter -K http://www.mydomain.com/ipad/crypt.key -k crypt.key -f /path/to/output /path/to/input/file
```

worked like a charm, albeit with warnings against using the same public key for multiple files.